# SLIMDX antialising

Tags: antialiasing, slimdx

I try to get the high qulity antialiasing from a tuturial I found on the internet (http://www.rkoenig.eu/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=21:chapter-3-das-erste-echte-3d-objekt&catid=6:directx10-basics&Itemid=3). But did not achieve a very good solution.

I already set the multisampling to the maximum:

```
m_swapChainDesc.SampleDescription = new DXGI.SampleDescription(8,0);
```

To me it appears as the pixel size of the rendered image is larger than the actual pixel size of my screen.

Thank you very much in advance for your valuable inputs

here is the complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using SlimDX;

using DX10 = SlimDX.Direct3D10;
using DXGI = SlimDX.DXGI;

namespace TutorialSeries.DirectX10.Chapter3
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Form
    {
        private DX10.Device m_device;
        private DXGI.SwapChainDescription m_swapChainDesc;
        private DXGI.SwapChain m_swapChain;
        private DXGI.Factory m_factory;
        private DX10.RenderTargetView m_renderTarget;
        private bool m_initialized;

        private SimpleBox m_simpleBox;

        private Matrix m_viewMatrix;
        private Matrix m_projMatrix;
        private Matrix m_worldMatrix;
        private Matrix m_viewProjMatrix;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes device and other resources needed for rendering. Returns true, if successful.
        /// </summary>
        private bool Initialize3D()
        {
            try
            {
                m_device = new DX10.Device(DX10.DriverType.Warp, DX10.DeviceCreationFlags.SingleThreaded);

                m_factory = new DXGI.Factory();

                m_swapChainDesc = new DXGI.SwapChainDescription();
                m_swapChainDesc.OutputHandle = this.Handle;
                m_swapChainDesc.IsWindowed = true;
                m_swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 1;
                m_swapChainDesc.Flags = DXGI.SwapChainFlags.AllowModeSwitch;
                m_swapChainDesc.ModeDescription = new DXGI.ModeDescription(
                    this.Width,
                    this.Height,
                    new Rational(60, 1),
                    DXGI.Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm);
                m_swapChainDesc.SampleDescription = new DXGI.SampleDescription(8,0);
                m_swapChainDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI.SwapEffect.Discard;
                m_swapChainDesc.Usage = DXGI.Usage.RenderTargetOutput;

                m_swapChain = new DXGI.SwapChain(m_factory, m_device, m_swapChainDesc);



                DX10.Viewport viewPort = new DX10.Viewport();
                viewPort.X = 0;
                viewPort.Y = 0;
                viewPort.Width = this.Width;
                viewPort.Height = this.Height;
                viewPort.MinZ = 0f;
                viewPort.MaxZ = 1f;

                //DX10.Texture2D backBuffer = m_swapChain.GetBuffer<DX10.Texture2D>(0);
                DX10.Texture2D Texture = DX10.Texture2D.FromSwapChain<DX10.Texture2D>(m_swapChain,0);

                //m_renderTarget = new DX10.RenderTargetView(m_device, backBuffer);
                //DX10.RenderTargetViewDescription renderDesc = new DX10.RenderTargetViewDescription();
                //renderDesc.FirstArraySlice = 0;
                //renderDesc.MipSlice = 0;

                m_renderTarget = new DX10.RenderTargetView(m_device, Texture);

                Texture.Dispose();

                DX10.RasterizerStateDescription rsd = new DX10.RasterizerStateDescription();
                rsd.CullMode = DX10.CullMode.Back;
                rsd.FillMode = DX10.FillMode.Wireframe;
                rsd.IsMultisampleEnabled = true;
                rsd.IsAntialiasedLineEnabled = false;
                rsd.IsDepthClipEnabled = false;
                rsd.IsScissorEnabled = false;

               DX10.RasterizerState RasterStateWireFrame = DX10.RasterizerState.FromDescription(m_device,rsd);

                DX10.BlendStateDescription blendDesc = new DX10.BlendStateDescription();
                blendDesc.BlendOperation = DX10.BlendOperation.Add;
                blendDesc.AlphaBlendOperation = DX10.BlendOperation.Add;
                blendDesc.SourceAlphaBlend = DX10.BlendOption.Zero;
                blendDesc.DestinationAlphaBlend = DX10.BlendOption.Zero;
                blendDesc.SourceBlend = DX10.BlendOption.SourceColor;
                blendDesc.DestinationBlend = DX10.BlendOption.Zero;
                blendDesc.IsAlphaToCoverageEnabled = false;
                blendDesc.SetWriteMask(0, DX10.ColorWriteMaskFlags.All);
                blendDesc.SetBlendEnable(0, true);
                DX10.BlendState m_blendState = DX10.BlendState.FromDescription(m_device, blendDesc);

                m_device.Rasterizer.State = RasterStateWireFrame;
                m_device.Rasterizer.SetViewports(viewPort);
                m_device.OutputMerger.BlendState = m_blendState;
                m_device.OutputMerger.SetTargets(m_renderTarget);

                m_viewMatrix = Matrix.LookAtLH(
                    new Vector3(0f, 0f, -4f),
                    new Vector3(0f, 0f, 1f),
                    new Vector3(0f, 1f, 0f));
                m_projMatrix = Matrix.PerspectiveFovLH(
                    (float)Math.PI * 0.5f,
                    this.Width / (float)this.Height,
                    0.1f, 100f);
                m_viewProjMatrix = m_viewMatrix * m_projMatrix;
                m_worldMatrix = Matrix.RotationYawPitchRoll(0.85f, 0.85f, 0f);

                m_simpleBox = new SimpleBox();
                m_simpleBox.LoadResources(m_device);

                m_initialized = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error while initializing Direct3D10: \n" + ex.Message);
                m_initialized = false;
            }

            return m_initialized;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Rendering is done during the standard OnPaint event
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);

            if (m_initialized)
            {
                m_device.ClearRenderTargetView(m_renderTarget, new Color4(Color.CornflowerBlue));

                m_simpleBox.Render(m_device, m_worldMatrix, m_viewProjMatrix);

                m_swapChain.Present(0, DXGI.PresentFlags.None);
            }
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Initialize 3D-Graphics within OnLoad event
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            Initialize3D();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but it's a shame it never got answered; I stumbled across it on Google so I figure answering it may help someone else in the future...

First of all, Pascal, you did NOT set MSAA to the maximum... You're using 8:0, which means 8 samples at a quality of 0 (zero)... definitely not the maximum. What the "max" is depends on the GPU installed on the local machine. So it varies from PC to PC. That's why a DirectX application needs to use DXGI to properly enumerate hardware devices and determine what settings are valid. This is no trivial topic and will require you to do some research and practice of your own. The DirectX SDK Documentation and samples/tutorials are a great starting place, and there's a lot of other materials to be found online. But on my machine, for instance, my GTX-580 GPU can support 8:16 MSAA (possibly higher, but haven't checked).

So you need to learn to use DXGI to enumerate your graphics cards and monitors and figure out what MSAA levels (and other graphics features/settings) it can support. That's the only way you'll ever figure out the "max" MSAA settings or the correct refresh rate of your monitor, for example. If you're clever you will write yourself a small library or component for your game engine that will enumerate hardware devices for you and figure out the optimal graphics settings so you won't have to re-do this over and over for future projects.

Regards,

--ATC--